# Consul and isolation of operations

Tags: consul

Some business logic is using Consul KV in the following way:

- check if `val1` exist
- check if `val2` exist
- if validation is ok, puts object to `/val1/val2/`

Obviously, these checks are 3 separate request to Consul cluster. How can I be sure that all 3 from this example be isolated (locked)?

I want to make sure that eg. `val2` does not appear *after* the check (executed by another thread/user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to synchronize access to something then you need a synchronization mechanism called [lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)). In your situation (different processes) it is more correctly to call it "distributed lock".

You can implement it yourself but actually Consul has it inside, see https://www.consul.io/docs/commands/lock.html

So your business logic in all parts of code that somehow access (read/modify) `val1` and `val2` must be wrapped in lock asquisition/releasing mechanism:

- asquire lock
- check if val1 exist
- check if val2 exist
- if validation is ok, puts object to /val1/val2/
- release lock

Comment: Thanx, we did that; just to realize it is not so... efficient on higher load. Plus, it does not offer isolation.